# How to modify the kernel density estimate line in a sns.histplot

Tags: python, seaborn, kdeplot, displot, histplot

I am creating a histrogram (frecuency vs. count) and I want to add kernel density estimate line in a different colour. How can I do this? I want to change the colour for example

`sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True)`

[image]

Example taken from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`histplot`'s `line_kws={...}` is meant to change the appearance of the kde line. However, the current seaborn version doesn't allow changing the color that way, probably because the color goes together with the `hue` parameter (although `hue` isn't used in this case).

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
ax = sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True,
                  line_kws={'color': 'crimson', 'lw': 5, 'ls': ':'})
```

[image: histplot changing kde line parameters]

In [seaborn's github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2344), it is suggested to draw the `histplot` and the `kdeplot` separately.  For both to match in the y-direction, it is necessary to use `histplot` with `stat='density'` (the `kdeplot` doesn't have a parameter to use `histplot`'s default `stat='count'`).

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
ax = sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=False, stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", color='crimson', ax=ax)
```

[image: sns.histplot and sns.kdeplot separately]

If the `count` statistics is really needed, an alternative is to change the line color via matplotlib:

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
ax = sns.histplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", kde=True)
ax.lines[0].set_color('crimson')
```

[image: changing line color of sns.histplot with kde=True]