# color parameter isn't changing the plot color

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, displot, histplot

Following is the code that doesn't work.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.displot(pd.DataFrame(res), color='red', edgecolor=None, binwidth=.5, binrange=(3, 18+1));
```

`res` is a list type.

I was expecting the bars to be red, but they are the default color.

I had no problem before with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The correct approach to setting the color of a single group, depends on how, or if, `data=` is specified, and if `x=`, or `y=`, is specified.
- The same issue applies to `g = sns.histplot(data=df, color='r', legend=False)`, as shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCjui.png).

  - The following implementations also apply to `histplot`.
- See [How to modify the kernel density estimate line in a sns.histplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69525485/7758804) for changing the line color for `kde=True`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### Imports and Data

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# random normal data as a list
np.random.seed(2023)
res = np.random.normal(loc=75, scale=5, size=1000).tolist()

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(res)

# df.head() - the column header is the number 0, not string '0'

           0
0  78.558368
1  73.377575
2  69.990647
3  76.181254
4  74.489201
```

### Plot Implementation

- Pass `df`, and do not specify a column name for `x=`, requires passing a `dict` or a `list` to `palette`.

  - `palette` will also accept a string, but the string must be a valid palette name, `ValueError: 'r' is not a valid palette name`
- The color saturation is different when using `palette`, compared to `color`, so pass `alpha=` (number 0 - 1) to adjust as needed.

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, palette={0: 'r'})  # from v0.13.0 this does not work, because hue must also be specified
g = sns.displot(data=df, palette=['r'])  # from v0.13.0 this does not work, because hue must also be specified
```

- Pass `df`, and specify a column name for `x=`

```py
g = sns.displot(data=df, x=0, color='r')
```

- Pass the column to `x=`

```py
g = sns.displot(x=df[0], color='r')
```

- Pass `res` directly to `data=`

```py
g = sns.displot(data=res, color='r')
```

- Pass `res` directly to `x=`

```py
g = sns.displot(x=res, color='r')
```

[image]

[image]